# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlsplit'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlsplit

I'm trying to figure out why I am seeing an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlsplit'

When I try to install `urlsplit` with pip, I am seeing that this module doesn't exist. When I try to install `urllib.split` with pip I see the same message:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urlsplit (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for urlsplit

What am I missing here?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlsplit
from zoomeye_search import *
from shodan_search import *
from censys_search import *
from random import choice
import requests, cfscrape
import argparse
import re

# “Never underestimate the determination of a kid who is time-rich and cash-poor.”

def banner():

        color = ['\033[95m' , '\033[96m', '\033[36m' , '\033[94m' , '\033[92m' , '\033[93m' , '\033[91m']

        print(choice(color) + ''' 
               _                                  
              (`  ).                   _           
             (     ).              .:(`  )`.       
)           _(       '`.          :(   .    )      
        .=(`(      .   )     .--  `.  (    ) )      
       ((    (..__.:'-'   .+(   )   ` _`  ) )                 
`.     `(       ) )       (   .  )     (   )  ._   
  )      ` __.:'   )     (   (   ))     `-'.-(`  ) 
)  )  ( )       --'       `- __.'         :(      )) 
.-'  (_.'          .')                    `(    )  ))
                  (_  )                     ` __.:'    

                    /|      __  
                   / |   ,-~ /  
                  Y :|  //  /    
                  | jj /( .^  
                  >-"~"-v"  
                 /       Y    
                jo  o    |  
               ( ~T~     j   
                >._-' _./   
               /   "~"  |    
              Y     _,  |      
             /| ;-"~ _  l    
            / l/ ,-"~    \  
            \//\/      .- \  
             Y        /    Y*  
             l       I     ! 
             ]\      _\    /"\ 
            (" ~----( ~   Y.  )   
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    
CloudBunny - Bypass WAF with Search Engines 
Author: Eddy Oliveira (@Warflop)
https://github.com/Warflop \033[0m
    ''')

def banner_footer():

        color = ['\033[95m' , '\033[96m', '\033[36m' , '\033[94m' , '\033[92m' , '\033[93m' , '\033[91m']

        print(choice(color) + ''' 

  /\\=//\-"""-.        
 / /6 6\ \     \        
  =\_Y_/=  (_  ;{}     
    /^//_/-/__/      
    "" ""  """       
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    We may have some false positives :)
\033[0m
        ''')

def search(url):

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

        try:

                if not re.match(r'http(s?)\:', url):
                        url = 'http://' + url
                        scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
                        data  = scraper.get(url,headers=headers)
                else:
                        scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
                        data  = scraper.get(url,headers=headers)

        except:

                print("Hey buddy, pass a real address please!")
                exit(1)
                return

        if data.status_code == 200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
                for link in soup.title:
                    return link
        else:
                print("We had a problem with the URL!")
                exit(1)

def main():

        resolver = []
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("-u", '--url', help="Hey buddy, can you give me the URL to test?")
        parser.add_argument("-s", '--shodan', action="store_true", help="Use Shodan")
        parser.add_argument("-c", '--censys', action="store_true", help="Use Censys")
        parser.add_argument("-z", '--zoomeye', action="store_true", help="Use ZoomEye")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        title = search(args.url).encode('utf-8')
        host = split_url(args.url)

        if args.shodan or args.censys or args.zoomeye:

                if args.shodan:
                        banner()
                        print("[+] Looking for target on Shodan...")
                        if not shodan_search(title) is None:
                                for shodan_target in shodan_search(title):
                                        if not shodan_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(shodan_target)

                if args.censys:
                        print("[+] Looking for target on Censys...")
                        if not censys_search(title) is None:
                                for censys_target in censys_search(title):
                                        if not censys_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(censys_target)

                        print("[+] Looking for certificates on Censys...")
                        if not censys_search_certs(host) is None:
                                for censys_target_cert in censys_search_certs(host):
                                        if not censys_target_cert in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(censys_target_cert)

                if args.zoomeye:
                        print("[+] Looking for target on ZoomEye...")
                        if not zoomeye_search(title) is None:
                                for zoomeye_target in zoomeye_search(title):
                                        if not zoomeye_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(zoomeye_target)

                if resolver:
                        print("[*] We found some data wait just one more second...")
                        print("\n")
                        result_search(resolver)
                else:
                        print("\n")
                        print("[-] Looks like our rabbit has not gotten so deep. :(")

                banner_footer()

        else:
                        banner()
                        print("[+] Looking for target on Shodan...")
                        if not shodan_search(title) is None:
                                for shodan_target in shodan_search(title):
                                        if not shodan_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(shodan_target)

                        print("[+] Looking for target on Censys...")
                        if not censys_search(title) is None:
                                for censys_target in censys_search(title):
                                        if not censys_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(censys_target)

                        print("[+] Looking for certificates on Censys...")
                        if not censys_search_certs(host) is None:
                                for censys_target_cert in censys_search_certs(host):
                                        if not censys_target_cert in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(censys_target_cert)

                        print("[+] Looking for target on ZoomEye...")
                        if not zoomeye_search(title) is None:
                                for zoomeye_target in zoomeye_search(title):
                                        if not zoomeye_target in resolver:
                                                resolver.append(zoomeye_target)

                        if resolver:
                                print("[-] Just more some seconds...")
                                print("\n")
                                result_search(resolver)
                        else:
                                print("\n")
                                print("[-] Looks like our rabbit has not gotten so deep. :(")

                        banner_footer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to import it like

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
```

`urllib` is a built-in library and you don't need to install it separately

`urlparse` is an old library name from Python 2. It was renamed in Python 3